# Python 3.5 + windows 10 + ffmpeg, завершить процес

Tags: python, windows, ffmpeg

В windows, в python 3.5 через Popen пытаюсь запустить ffmpeg, но его надо убить через определенное время, но в windows, видео получается 8-10 секунд, в Unix системе, ffpmeg пишет как и задумывалось 20 секунд.

```
process = subprocess.Popen(
    [ffmpeg_path, '-i', rstp_url, '-c:v', 'copy', '-c:a', 'aac', '-t', str(60), filename],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

time.sleep(20)
process.communicate(b'q')
```

Comment: Можно поинтересоваться, зачем? Вижу, что вы используете опцию `-t` — чем она не угодила? Убиванием процесса вы никогда не добьётесь точной длительности, потому что она зависит от кучи разных факторов.

Comment: Да опция -t делает то, что нужно. Мне не нужна точность. Вообщем суть в следующим, опцией -t задаю максимальное время ролика, а затем в случае отсутствия тревожных событий надо перестать писать видео.
Для этого и используется `process.communicate(b'q')`, под linux все прекрасно работает, а вот под окнами нет..

Comment: Если точность не нужна, то и 8-10 секунд вас должно устроить) А точнее вряд ли получится.

Comment: А вообще можно попробовать дописать `-progress -` и тогда в stdout будет печататься информация о прогрессе, в том числе длительность. Читаете, ждёте нужную длительность, останавливаете

Comment: так при любом `time.sleep(10-60)` мы получаем 8-10 секунд записи

Comment: Ну так это очень важное дополнение, которое обязано быть в тексте вопроса. Тогда вообще уберите time.sleep и process.communicate(b'q') и посмотрите что будет

Comment: И вообще универсальный совет — читайте логи ffmpeg

Comment: Если убрать эти две строки, то запишет 60 секунд, ну 59, секунда на старт.

Comment: Тут я уже начинаю вам немножко не верить, пойду сам в Windows проверю

Comment: Воообще это какая то проблема питона, если в `cmd` запустить ffmpeq и затем в случайное время нажать q, то запишется нужное кол-во секунд, а через `Popen` всегда 8-10

Comment: Кажется, до меня дошло, что происходит, если кратко — уберите `stderr=subprocess.PIPE`

Comment: Действительно, после того, как убрал `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` все записалось, как положено, правда в консоль вывалился мусор от `ffmpeg`
А можно пояснить почему так происходит?

Comment: `-loglevel error`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда вы пишете `subprocess.PIPE`, данные из пайпа (в данном случае нас интересует stderr), пока вы их не прочитали в своей программе, складываются во **временный буфер ограниченного размера** — в моём случае он оказался 4096 байт. Вы ничего из stderr не читаете, поэтому этот временный буфер не чистится и постепенно заполняется.

Когда в буфере кончается место, процесс **зависает** при попытке что-нибудь записать до тех пор, пока буфер не освободится.

Теперь давайте посчитаем, как быстро буфер заполнится.

При запуске сперва ffmpeg пишет информацию о себе:

```
ffmpeg version 4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.2.1 (GCC) 20181017
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth

  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
```

Это **1243** байта. *(Плюс-минус несколько байт на разные версии, переносы строк и так далее — не буду считать абсолютно точно.)*

Дальше пишется информация о входящих потоках:

```
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://admin:123456@192.168.1.254/stream':
  Metadata:
    title           : 11
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p(progressive), 640x352, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_alaw, 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_alaw (native) -> aac (native))
```

У всех будет немножко по-разному, но в моём случае получилось **459** байт.

Когда начинается запись, ffmpeg пишет информацию о выходных потоках:

```
Output #0, mp4, to './rtsp_test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    title           : 11
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 640x352, q=2-31, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 8000 Hz, mono, fltp, 48 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 aac
```

У меня это **370** байт.

В сумме это всё 1243 + 459 + 370 = **2072** байта. Буфер заполнен уже наполовину.

В процессе записи ffmpeg каждые полсекунды печатает такую строчку с информацией о прогрессе:

```
frame=  107 fps= 27 q=-1.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:05.27 bitrate=   0.1kbits/s speed=1.31x
```

Длина каждый раз разная, но давайте возьмём среднюю **100** байт.

Посчитаем, сколько раз ffmpeg сможет отпечатать эту строчку:

(4096 - 2072) // 100 = 20 раз.

Одна строчка каждые полсекунды — это 20 * 0.5 = **10 секунд записи до тех пор, пока буфер stderr не заполнится**.

После этого ffmpeg пытается отпечатать следующую строчку в stderr, упирается в заполнившийся буфер, **зависает** и больше ничего не записывает.

---

Решение — не допускать заполнение буфера. Как именно — вариантов несколько:

- избавиться от перехвата вывода. Если вы просто уберёте из кода `stderr=subprocess.PIPE`, то всё будет выводиться в командную строку, и ничего не переполнится. *(здесь по идее также должен был подойти DEVNULL, но у меня в Windows он не заработал)*;
- своевременно читать данные из буфера, чтобы он не успевал заполниться. Для этого в вашем случае понадобится перевести stderr в неблокирующий режим (как — тема для отдельного вопроса, к тому же в Windows с причудами) и делать постоянный read() в каком-нибудь цикле (можно напару с select(), но это опять же тема для отдельного вопроса);
- попросить ffmpeg меньше печатать. Если заткнуть его каким-нибудь `-loglevel warning` или другим менее подробным режимом, то весь описанный выше вывод будет отсутствовать. Однако ffmpeg продолжит печатать информацию об ошибках, и буфер всё равно заполнится — не через десять секунд, так через час. Поэтому лучше так не делать, или хотя бы комбинировать с первым вариантом.

Comment: На самом деле в Linux происходит всё то же самое, но там размер буфера целых 65536 байт и он просто не успевает переполниться за минуту.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, за подробный и развернутый ответ