# Не могу остановить subprocess

Tags: python, windows, ffmpeg, subprocess

У меня есть вот такая команда:

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i desktop output.mkv
```

Если запустить её через cmd, она будет ожидать нажатия клавиши q и потом завершаться.
**Моя задача запустить её через Popen, заснуть на 5 секунд(на самом деле мне не надо "спать" какое-то время, просто для описания проблемы это подойдёт) и завершить её.**

После создания command в главном процессе python появляется ещё 3 подпроцесса: `python`, `ffmpeg.exe`, `Windows Command Processor`

```
command = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Я пробовал это:

```py
def record():
    command = 'ffmpeg -loglevel panic -hide_banner -y -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i desktop output.mkv'
    command = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    sleep(5)
    command.stdin.write('q'.encode('utf-8'))
    command.stdin.flush()
    while True:
        if command.poll():  # False
            print(command.poll())
            break
        sleep(.2)
record()
print('stop')
```

Этот код не сработал. Я посмотрел в task manager, там было видно, что процесс ffmpeg.exe не остановлен.
Далее я решил попробовать это:

```
command = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
sleep(5)
command.terminate()
while True:
    if command.poll():
        print(command.poll()) # output 1
        break
    sleep(.2)
```

Этот код говорит, что процесс завершился, хотя на самом деле процесс `ffmpeg.exe` всё ещё "жив".
Далее я просто заменил `command.terminate()` на `command.kill()`
и запустил тот же код. В результате всё то же самое.
Этот код говорит, что процесс завершился, хотя на самом деле, процесс `ffmpeg.exe` всё ещё "жив".
)
Как позже выяснилось, этот код убил `Windows Command Processor`

Потом я попробовал убить процесс с помощью такой команды:

```
taskkill /F /IM "ffmpeg.exe"
```

Эта команда сработала, она убила процесс ffmpeg.exe, но выходной файл(output.mkv) после моей команды не открывался.
Я думаю, это связано с тем, что мы убили процесс, а не передали туда сигнал "q" и тем самым не дали ему спокойно завершиться.
**Как можно передать процессу ffmpeg.exe сигнал "q" и дать ему спокойно завершиться?**

Comment: Во-первых, после write попробуйте `command.stdin.flush()`

Comment: Во-вторых, если вы уж сделали PIPE для stdout и stderr, то вы **должны** их читать, иначе буфер переполнится, ffmpeg зависнет и не сможет завершиться. Если вы их не хотите читать, то уберите PIPE или поставьте вместо них DEVNULL

Comment: Про PIPE я уже писал подробнее тут: [Python 3.5 + windows 10 + ffmpeg, завершить процес](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/938474)

Comment: @andreymal
def record():
    command = 'ffmpeg -loglevel panic -hide_banner -y -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i desktop output.mkv'
    command = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    sleep(5)
    command.stdin.write('q'.encode('utf-8'))
    command.stdin.flush()
    while True:
        if command.poll():  # False
            print(command.poll())
            break
        sleep(.2)
record()
print('stop')
Этот код не работает, сообщение stop никогда не выведется

Comment: @andreymal, добавил этот код в вопрос, и спасибо вам за помощь

Comment: @но output.mkv валидный, ровно 5 секунд.
Мне кажется что command - другой процесс(windows command processor), и этот код(    while True:
        if command.poll():  # False
            print(command.poll())
            break
        sleep(.2)) бесполезен. Как я могу проверить завершился ли процесс ffmpeg.exe?

Comment: @Nikto - мой второй аккаунт

Comment: shell=True убери чтоб не запускался cmd и убиваться будет сразу ффмпег

Comment: мультиакк надо банить;)

Comment: Условие `if command.poll()` никогда не будет истинным, потому что после завершения своей работы ffmpeg вернёт 0

Comment: Думаю свой ответ принимать будет как-то неправильно.
Но решение опубликую

Answer (score 0):

```py
def record():
    command = 'ffmpeg -loglevel panic -hide_banner -y -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i desktop output.mkv'
    command = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    sleep(5)
    command.stdin.write('q'.encode('utf-8'))
    command.stdin.flush()
    while True:
        if command.poll() == 0:
            break
        sleep(.2)
record()
```

Comment: Если ffmpeg по какой-то причине завершит свою работу некорректно, то условие `if command.poll() == 0` никогда не будет истинным

Comment: @andreymal, а что тогда делать?

Comment: `if command.poll() is not None`

Comment: Или вообще просто `command.wait()` без всяких условий и странных циклов

Comment: @andreyma, спасибо, буду юзать wait()

Comment: @andreymal, извините, похоже мне придётся ещё чуть-чуть вас по беспокоить. Если в качестве выходного файла я например, напишу file.img, то ffmpeg выдаст ошибку: не поддерживаемый формат.Как я могу постоянно читать stderr, чтобы поймать эту ошибку? Спасибо

Comment: Сложный вопрос, в винде с этим дела плохи. Задайте отдельный вопрос на эту тему, может кто знает кроме меня